# Updating sitemap from django to google webmaster doesn't work

Tags: python, django, sitemap, urllib, google-search-console

Our website gets updated almost everyday. We need to update the sitemap to the google webmasters every time there are new pages added.

We have tried using ping_google() along with the required set of arguments and google and it never seem to update the sitemap on webmasters. To log the response, we re-wrote the function and logged the response given below:

```
    2010-10-01 09:00:02,489 DEBUG Sitemap Response: <html><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<head><title>Google Webmaster Tools
-
Sitemap Notification Received</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, noodp">
<script src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     _uacct="UA-18009-2";
     _utcp="/webmasters/";
     _uanchor=1;
     urchinTracker();
   </script></head>
<body><h2>Sitemap Notification Received</h2>
<br>
Your Sitemap has been successfully added to our list of Sitemaps to crawl. If this is the first time you are notifying Google about this Sitemap, please add it via  <a href="http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/">http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/</a>  so you can track its status. Please note that we do not add all submitted URLs to our index, and we cannot make any predictions or guarantees about when or if they will appear.</body></html>
```

The response seem to look fine. But the sitemap never gets updated on webmasters. We are using django 1.1. Is there any alternative to update the sitemap on webmasters other than the ping_google()

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the link to your sitemaps file.

If you have set priority for most of the URL's in your sitemap high, google might think it's kind of spamming and will not bother to download sitemap.

Also check the change frequency in your sitemap.

If your sitemap is fine and content really changes everyday, google will automatically download it even if you don't ping it.